# How can I access only that key has value true? Object in an array

Tags: javascript

```
letters = [{
    A: true,
    B: false,
    C: false,
    D: false,
    E: false,
    F: false,
    G: false
}]
```

I came up with this solution. console.log(prop); now returns "$init A". I would only need "A". Is it because my array is in a mongodb database?

```
for (var prop in letters[0]) {
    if (letters[0][prop] === true) {
        console.log(prop);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean other than `letters[0].A`? What problem do you actually have?

Comment: Questions you need to answer first: Can multiple properties have value `true`? If so, what is the expected return value? What shall happen if there is no property with value `true`?

Comment: Trust me, I have tried enough. Just did not included them in the post as they were not successful.

Comment: I want letter A returned if it s value is true.

Comment: @ZsoltKindla According to your comment above, you specified this solution: `if (letters[0].A === true) return 'A'` - but I don't think this is what you actually want.

Comment: This is a "Why isn't my code working?" site, not a "My code isn't working, so please write some code for me" site. Post your non-working code, explain what it's supposed to do (including what should happen if more than one key is `true`, or if none is `true`) and what it's doing instead. Then you're very likely to get some help.

Comment: Ok. I will be more specific. The code is updated. I just did not post it before, because I know it is far away what I want. So all the letters intended have false value, but one will have true. I wanted to write a code, which returns the only one key has the true value.

Comment: @ZsoltKindla The objects are in an array. What if it's a different key in each array element?

Comment: Loop over the object properties with `for (key in object)`. If the value of a property is true, return the key. What's the problem?

Comment: If `prop` is supposed to be a variable, use `letters[0][prop]` (instead of `letters[0].prop`) in the `if` test. And what's `this.key`? Shouldn't you rather log the value of `prop`?

Comment: Barmar, I do not intend to use more than 1 array. That is why it is not important for me.

Comment: I have updated my code. Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var letters = [{
    A: true,
    B: false,
    C: false,
    D: false,
    E: false,
    F: false,
    G: false
}]
```

I came up with this solution. console.log(prop); now returns "$init A". I would only need "A". Is it because my array is in a mongodb database?

```
for (var prop in letters[0]) {
    if (letters[0][prop] === true) {
        console.log(prop);
    }
}
```

Finally I have made "$init" disappeared using jQuery in my seperated js file by:

```
$('td:contains("$init")').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().split("$init").join("<span hidden='true'>$init</span>"));
});
```

I would like to thank to all of you for your help and effort on this case. Probably it is not the cleanest solution, but does what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over all keys with `Object.keys()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

With `.filter` method and test inside if object[key] has some value